# Update database on html table edition (web app)

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a .jsp site that display data from mysql database in html table. Some of table data is contenteditable, so user is able to change data in this table. After table data edition I want to update exact row in database. How do I automatically run servlet/php script to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to creat at least ajax request or any kind of request that will be used to send or receive backend page which will handle the request and update the database.